# Ejecutar procedimiento almacenado con django-pyodbc-azure

Tags: python, django

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion con Django en el backend y necesito ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado de Sql server, ya instalé django-pyodbc-azure, y configuré la base de datos en el archivo settings.py, pero no sé como ejecutar el sp con ese paquete. OJO el paquete es django-pyodbc-azure NO pyodbc. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

No soy experto usando PyODBC, ni he usado esta versión, pero entiendo que al ser un fork del mismo debe funcionar de la misma manera que con PyODBC. Bueno, además de eso, tambien tendrías la opción de hacer un Raw Query con el ORM de Django a ver que te devuelve y como manejarlo. Este es un ejemplo que vi en la documentación de Django:

```
from django.db import connection

def my_custom_sql(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.callproc('test_procedure', [1, 'test'])
```

Hay una respuesta en el StackOverFlow que está en ingles:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43947566/818601
Y esta es la documentación de como hacer consultas a SP con Django:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#calling-stored-procedures

Saludos cordiales!